# Why adding a route here is throwing up an error?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, route

I have a linux Fedora -16 machine that has two interfaces -

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:CA:3A:89:EE:F1  
          inet addr:136.170.195.17  Bcast:136.170.195.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fec0::f:baca:3aff:fe89:eef1/64 Scope:Site
          inet6 addr: 2002:88aa:c268:f:baca:3aff:fe89:eef1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::baca:3aff:fe89:eef1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6363373 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1571017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4502189587 (4.1 GiB)  TX bytes:175801460 (167.6 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:85089 (83.0 KiB)  TX bytes:85089 (83.0 KiB)

p3p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:D6:4D:1F:F3:F8  
          inet addr:10.240.100.110  Bcast:10.240.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16d6:4dff:fe1f:f3f8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2615351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2868133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1081785835 (1.0 GiB)  TX bytes:1577912608 (1.4 GiB)
```

On the interface p3p1, I am running a dhcp server. My embedded device, which runs on a NFS, gets the IP address from p3p1. The p3p1 interface is connected to my embedded device - Point to Point.

Now, from the embedded box ( a linux based system), I want to ping/access the address - 136.170.195.17.

I cannot do the following because, the gw doesn't know how to route the packets for 136.170.0.0 subnet. So, I get an error -

```
 # ping 136.170.195.17
PING 136.170.195.17 (136.170.195.17): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

Since the communication is on the different network, I need to add the route in the device. So, what I have done is enabled the packet forwarding in my linux machine. Next, I have add the route like this.

```
# /sbin/route add net 136.170.192.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.240.100.110
route: resolving net
```

I am getting the above error. I think that my understanding of network is not in-correct. What is the reason that I am getting the following error? Actually, I am baffled with the above error. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong in my concepts like - enabling packet forwarding and adding the route for the packet destined for the different subnet. Because for the same subnet, the route doesn't come into the picture - it is just based on ARP.  How can I fix this issue? Is there any problem in my understanding?

Here is the box  routing table -

```
# netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.240.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Here is my PC routing table -

```
$ netstat -arn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         136.170.192.2   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
10.240.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 p3p1
136.170.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 p3p1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /sbin/route add net 136.170.192.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.240.100.110

Try `route add -net ...`.  I suspect that error message comes when your embedded device tries to resolve the name `net` to an address or network range.

Comment: Yup, it worked - -net was the culprit. If you wish, you can throw more details on this -net concept rather than net.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's nothing to add - you got the arguments to `route` wrong.  It's easily done, so don't worry about it - but to `UNIX` commands, punctuation matters!